# Get values of textfield only if checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i want to get the values of only select check boxes in this interface and every checkbox has its own value how can i do that its driving me crazy
[THIS][1] how can i do this

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>EFF 2016 theorique</title>
        <script>
            function Myfunction() {
                var repas = document.forms[0];
                var txt = 0;
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    if (repas[i].checked) {
                        txt = txt+ (parseInt(repas[i].value) * parseInt(document.getElementById("repase_"+i).value)) ;
                        document.getElementById("resultat").value = parseInt(txt.toString()).toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="test">this is test and it will change</p>
        <h1>Calcul valeur energetique d'un repas</h1>
        <h4>Choisir les elements qui composent votre repas</h4>
        <form>
            <pre>
          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="275" /> PAIN    <input type="text" id="repase_0" value="0" />     grammes

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="180" /> VIANDE  <input type="text" id="repase_1" value="0" />   grammes

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="04" /> LEGUMES  <input type="text" id="repase_2" value="0" />  grammes     

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="116" />  BANANE  <input type="text" id="repase_3" value="0" />   unites

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="80" /> POMMES    <input type="text" id="repase_4" value="0" />   unites

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="140" /> YAOURT   <input type="text" id="repase_5" value="0" />   unites
  
            </pre>
            <input type="button" value="CALCULER" onclick="Myfunction()"/>
            <pre>
             La valeur energetique de votre repas est : <input type="text" id="resultat" value="" />
            </pre>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

ck.imgur.com/gJaxa.png

[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHTLT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY5KPjkMTUAhVIo48KHR3UBDQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw&sig2=X9q9D3groKoJNKDbDnEDUQ) to find the checked element.and iterate with `forEach` then find the the next element value using [`nextElementSlibing`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjk9M2GkcTUAhUHOI8KHc6YC4EQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FNonDocumentTypeChildNode%2FnextElementSibling&usg=AFQjCNFkg2OywPqlHdzoMoQG_3dR91pjpw&sig2=4TCLlQKQaN1GETMMaDlGWg)

```js
function Myfunction() {
  var res = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').forEach(function(a) {
    res += parseFloat(a.nextElementSibling.value)
  })
  document.getElementById("resultat").value = res
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">this is test and it will change</p>
<h1>Calcul valeur energetique d'un repas</h1>
<h4>Choisir les elements qui composent votre repas</h4>
<form>
  <pre>
          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="275" /> PAIN    <input type="text" id="repase_0" value="0" />     grammes

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="180" /> VIANDE  <input type="text" id="repase_1" value="0" />   grammes

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="04" /> LEGUMES  <input type="text" id="repase_2" value="0" />  grammes     

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="116" />  BANANE  <input type="text" id="repase_3" value="0" />   unites

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="80" /> POMMES    <input type="text" id="repase_4" value="0" />   unites

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="140" /> YAOURT   <input type="text" id="repase_5" value="0" />   unites
  
            </pre>
  <input type="button" value="CALCULER" onclick="Myfunction()" />
  <pre>
             La valeur energetique de votre repas est : <input type="text" id="resultat" value="" />
            </pre>
</form>
```

Comment: you are welcome @Mr.Robot.My answer is solve your issue [mark it as a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it's helpful for the future visitors

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the checkboxes, you can get them with `var repas = document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');`

This is the final working code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EFF 2016 theorique</title>
  <script>
    function Myfunction() {
      var repas = document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
      var txt = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < repas.length; i++) {
        var repa = repas[i];
        if (repa.checked) {
          var value = parseInt(repa.value);
          var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("repase_" + i).value);
          txt += value * input;
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("resultat").value = txt.toString();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="test">this is test and it will change</p>
  <h1>Calcul valeur energetique d'un repas</h1>
  <h4>Choisir les elements qui composent votre repas</h4>
  <form>
    <pre>
          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="275" /> PAIN    <input type="text" id="repase_0" value="0" />     grammes

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="180" /> VIANDE  <input type="text" id="repase_1" value="0" />   grammes

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="04" /> LEGUMES  <input type="text" id="repase_2" value="0" />  grammes     

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="116" />  BANANE  <input type="text" id="repase_3" value="0" />   unites

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="80" /> POMMES    <input type="text" id="repase_4" value="0" />   unites

          <input type="checkbox" name="repas" value="140" /> YAOURT   <input type="text" id="repase_5" value="0" />   unites

            </pre>
    <input type="button" value="CALCULER" onclick="Myfunction()" />
    <pre>
             La valeur energetique de votre repas est : <input type="text" id="resultat" value="" />
            </pre>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
Iterate over chechboxes and populate result outside the for loop, there is no need to populate result in every for iteration.

```
            function Myfunction() {
            var repas = document.forms[0];
            var txt = 0;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                if(document.getElementsByName("repas")[i].checked){
                    txt = txt+ (parseInt(repas[i].value) * parseInt(document.getElementById("repase_"+i).value)) ;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("resultat").value = parseInt(txt.toString()).toString();
        }
```